# TeX Live Manager GUI shows Unicode codes instead of characters

Tags: texlive

Here is what I see when I start `tlmgr gui`:

[image]

I understand that this is Unicode code points instead of the real characters. I tried

```
tlmgr gui -font "DejaVuSans 14"
```

same result. It also ignores `LANGUAGE=en:en` and `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` environment settings.

Comment: write to the texlive mailing list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did. Only silence is the answer.

Comment: I don't see a message from you there.

Comment: Hmm... I just emailed `tex-live@tug.org`. I should have done something else?

Comment: the address is right, but I don't see it in the archives https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/

Comment: It's here: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2021-June/047192.html

Comment: ah I overlooked that. But you got two answers from Siep.

Comment: Oh, I thought, I was going to receive an answer in email. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... How can I reply there?

Comment: no idea ;-( sorry, I normally access the mailing list through a news reader and gmane.

Comment: What newsreader are you using? In ancient times I was using Omea Reader by JetBrains. It's long outdated, and I am not using Windows anymore, but I can't find anything that could be even a small fraction of Omea's great functionality.